# floated elements go missing from html lists

Tags: html, css, css-float, mobile-safari, safari

**IMPORTANT NOTE!**  I have only recreated this bug on a 1st generation iPhone running Safari 4.0 (528.16), but as I'm trying to make my site as widely compatible as possible this is still a potential issue...

The problem: floated elements in lists are not appearing on screen.  I have narrowed the issue down to the following combination of rules:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><p>hello</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

If I place a non-floated element inside the `<li>` tag following the `<p>`, then the text in the `<p>` becomes visible.

So far I have tested this on the latest versions of Chrome/IE/Firefox on Windows 7, Safari on an iPhone 4, and Chrome/Firefox/Opera on Android (4.2.1 ) and the problem described has `not` occurred

I repeat: **I have ONLY seen it occur on Safari 4.0**, but as I can't test every platform/browser version combination out there, I am concerned this issue may be more widespread.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also encountering this issue, however I am seeing it in Safari 5.1.7 in Windows 7.

My current hot-fix is unfortunately JavaScript-based:

```
    $('.listContainer').hide();
    $('.somethingElse').hide();
    $('.listContainer').show();
```

I don't exactly understand why this works, but as long as .somethingElse is a valid selector, the hide/show operation shouldn't get optimized away and will actually force Safari to render the list. Someone who actually understands the nuts and bolts of this could probably lend a more graceful solution, but that's the hack I'm using right now.

EDIT

The weird thing is that if I place the dynamically-generated HTML statically into the .html file I'm working in, there is no rendering problem in Safari. There's something lower-level going on here with how the DOM is constructed in Safari that's breaking this. It's also quite possible that I'm not following some standards for how new elements should be added to the DOM in real time.

Any help? Maybe I should add a question of my own.

**FINAL EDIT**

Alright, I got it working through CSS, now.

The solution is to give the list-items *overflow:hidden.*

I don't know why, but that solved my problem. Hope it solves yours. Give it a shot.

Comment: That solves the problem because setting `overflow:hidden` (or anything other than the default/inherited overflow value) on a container creates a new block context and clears the floats within.

Without that, their height won't take the floated internals into account, and you're left to the whim of browser styles, etc.  I'm surprised they don't collapse to 0 in more cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you've got `overflow:hidden` which is why your element move out of range. Actually, if you have any element with some width specified and `overflow: hidden` then you are trying to hide some internal tags

for eg:

```
<div style='width:200px'>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
<div style='float:left;'>asdfkl</div>
</div>
```

Then you are actually trying to **hide anything that goes out of given 200px width** Provided you have the **inner divs float** so that all of them are in same line/ section or div

Answer (score 0):

When there's a bunch of float elements, the parent element will not be able to calculate its height properly.

After all your float elements include an empty element as follows

`<div class="break"></div>`

`. break{
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
float: none;
}`